# use variable names in firebase rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an existing firebase project.  Every user can save data to a 'folder' with the same name as the userid of the user.
I use the rules like this

```
"$uid":{
    ".read":"auth.uid == $uid",
    ".write":"auth.uid == $uid"
  }
```

But now, the need of collaboration between multiple users has risen.
So, i can't use this rule anymore.
I made a new 'table' in firebase, called 'users' where i can save the users id and the according variable workingDir.
Of course, i would like to keep my database secure, but I don't have a clue to setup the firebase rules for that and use this workingDir variable.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have a look at this documentation on role-based access control: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#data-defined_attributes_and_roles, while it may not be exactly what you need, it should be a good starting place.

Comment: Thank you, i think i figured it out.  I will do some testing tomorrow